Why this tkinter GUI code behaves differently when inside a function?
This generate_GUI1 function does not generate some buttons on the GUI

# This file was generated by the Tkinter Designer by Parth Jadhav
# https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer


from pathlib import Path

# from tkinter import *
# Explicit imports to satisfy Flake8
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage
import os

CURRENT_PATH = os.getcwd()

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(CURRENT_PATH + r"\assets\frame1")

window = Tk()

window.geometry("1000x729")
window.configure(bg = "#4B0082")

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)


def generate_GUI1(Frame):


    canvas = Canvas(
    Frame,
    bg = "#4B0082",
    height = 729,
    width = 1000,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
    )

    canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    canvas.create_rectangle(
    248.0,
    0.0,
    1000.0,
    729.0,
    fill="#D9D9D9",
    outline="")

    canvas.create_rectangle(
    353.0,
    198.0,
    841.0,
    500.0,
    fill="#00827A",
    outline="")

    canvas.create_rectangle(
    353.0,
    149.0,
    841.0,
    198.0,
    fill="#210082",
    outline="")

    canvas.create_text(
    363.0,
    164.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="VarianteID",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_text(
    461.0,
    164.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="ProductoID",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_text(
    570.0,
    164.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="TallaID",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_text(
    647.0,
    164.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="ColorID",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_text(
    742.0,
    164.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="SKU",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
    )

    button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
    button_1 = Button(
    image=button_image_1,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_1 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_1.place(
    x=353.0,
    y=87.0,
    width=185.0,
    height=36.0
    )

    button_image_2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_2.png"))
    button_2 = Button(
    image=button_image_2,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_2 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_2.place(
    x=380.0,
    y=542.0,
    width=113.0,
    height=50.0
    )

    button_image_3 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_3.png"))
    button_3 = Button(
    image=button_image_3,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_3 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_3.place(
    x=536.0,
    y=543.0,
    width=118.0,
    height=50.0
    )

    button_image_4 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_4.png"))
    button_4 = Button(
    image=button_image_4,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_4 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_4.place(
    x=704.0,
    y=543.0,
    width=118.0,
    height=50.0
    )

    canvas.create_rectangle(
    0.0,
    0.0,
    248.0,
    729.0,
    fill="#008282",
    outline="")

    image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
    image_1 = canvas.create_image(
    115.0,
    89.0,
    image=image_image_1
    )

    button_image_5 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_5.png"))
    button_5 = Button(
    image=button_image_5,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_5 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_5.place(
    x=25.0,
    y=480.0,
    width=198.0,
    height=45.0
    )

    button_image_6 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_6.png"))
    button_6 = Button(
    image=button_image_6,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_6 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_6.place(
    x=25.0,
    y=171.0,
    width=198.0,
    height=51.0
    )

    button_image_7 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_7.png"))
    button_7 = Button(
    image=button_image_7,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_7 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_7.place(
    x=25.0,
    y=253.0,
    width=198.0,
    height=44.0
    )

    button_image_8 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_8.png"))
    button_8 = Button(
    image=button_image_8,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_8 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_8.place(
    x=25.0,
    y=328.0,
    width=198.0,
    height=45.0
    )

    button_image_9 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_9.png"))
    button_9 = Button(
    image=button_image_9,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_9 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_9.place(
    x=25.0,
    y=404.0,
    width=198.0,
    height=45.0
    )

    button_image_10 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_10.png"))
    button_10 = Button(
    image=button_image_10,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_10 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_10.place(
    x=25.0,
    y=556.0,
    width=198.0,
    height=45.0
    )

    button_image_11 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_11.png"))
    button_11 = Button(
    image=button_image_11,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_11 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    button_11.place(
    x=25.0,
    y=632.0,
    width=198.0,
    height=45.0
    )
    return


generate_GUI1(window)


window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()


This is not what I expected, but for some reason by writing the code inside the function outside, now I get all the buttons that must appears in the GUI.

from pathlib import Path

# from tkinter import *
# Explicit imports to satisfy Flake8
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage
import os

CURRENT_PATH = os.getcwd()

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(CURRENT_PATH + r"\assets\frame1")

window = Tk()

window.geometry("1000x729")
window.configure(bg = "#4B0082")

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)



canvas = Canvas(
window,
bg = "#4B0082",
height = 729,
width = 1000,
bd = 0,
highlightthickness = 0,
relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
canvas.create_rectangle(
248.0,
0.0,
1000.0,
729.0,
fill="#D9D9D9",
outline="")

canvas.create_rectangle(
353.0,
198.0,
841.0,
500.0,
fill="#00827A",
outline="")

canvas.create_rectangle(
353.0,
149.0,
841.0,
198.0,
fill="#210082",
outline="")

canvas.create_text(
363.0,
164.0,
anchor="nw",
text="VarianteID",
fill="#FFFFFF",
font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
461.0,
164.0,
anchor="nw",
text="ProductoID",
fill="#FFFFFF",
font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
570.0,
164.0,
anchor="nw",
text="TallaID",
fill="#FFFFFF",
font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
647.0,
164.0,
anchor="nw",
text="ColorID",
fill="#FFFFFF",
font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
742.0,
164.0,
anchor="nw",
text="SKU",
fill="#FFFFFF",
font=("Inter ExtraLightItalic", 15 * -1)
)

button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
button_1 = Button(
image=button_image_1,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_1 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_1.place(
x=353.0,
y=87.0,
width=185.0,
height=36.0
)

button_image_2 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_2.png"))
button_2 = Button(
image=button_image_2,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_2 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_2.place(
x=380.0,
y=542.0,
width=113.0,
height=50.0
)

button_image_3 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_3.png"))
button_3 = Button(
image=button_image_3,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_3 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_3.place(
x=536.0,
y=543.0,
width=118.0,
height=50.0
)

button_image_4 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_4.png"))
button_4 = Button(
image=button_image_4,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_4 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_4.place(
x=704.0,
y=543.0,
width=118.0,
height=50.0
)

canvas.create_rectangle(
0.0,
0.0,
248.0,
729.0,
fill="#008282",
outline="")

image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
image_1 = canvas.create_image(
115.0,
89.0,
image=image_image_1
)

button_image_5 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_5.png"))
button_5 = Button(
image=button_image_5,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_5 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_5.place(
x=25.0,
y=480.0,
width=198.0,
height=45.0
)

button_image_6 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_6.png"))
button_6 = Button(
image=button_image_6,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_6 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_6.place(
x=25.0,
y=171.0,
width=198.0,
height=51.0
)

button_image_7 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_7.png"))
button_7 = Button(
image=button_image_7,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_7 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_7.place(
x=25.0,
y=253.0,
width=198.0,
height=44.0
)

button_image_8 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_8.png"))
button_8 = Button(
image=button_image_8,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_8 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_8.place(
x=25.0,
y=328.0,
width=198.0,
height=45.0
)

button_image_9 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_9.png"))
button_9 = Button(
image=button_image_9,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_9 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_9.place(
x=25.0,
y=404.0,
width=198.0,
height=45.0
)

button_image_10 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_10.png"))
button_10 = Button(
image=button_image_10,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_10 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_10.place(
x=25.0,
y=556.0,
width=198.0,
height=45.0
)

button_image_11 = PhotoImage(
file=relative_to_assets("button_11.png"))
button_11 = Button(
image=button_image_11,
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
command=lambda: print("button_11 clicked"),
relief="flat"
)
button_11.place(
x=25.0,
y=632.0,
width=198.0,
height=45.0
)




window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()


I need to import this generate_GUI function that's why I coded it, any suggestions to solve this behavior?

I assume it's due to garbage-collection. All your widgets go out-of-scope when the generate_GUI1 function terminates, whereas if the widgets exist in global scope they persist. You may benefit from making your function a method of a class, and then having a persistent instance of that class in global scope.

there is bug in PhotoImage which removes images when they are assigned to local variables. It needs to assign them to global variable or assign to  other objects - e.g. Frame.image_1 = button_image_1

there is good rule to use lower_case_names for variables - e.g. frame instead of Frame. And use CamelCaseNames only for classes. Besides if you use variable Frame in def generate_GUI1(Frame): then you can use real Frame() to create other frame inside function. More: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

did you run code from different folder? I thing using os.getcwd() will not work if you run it from different folder. It may need to use ASSETS_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / "assets" / "frame1"

Alternatively keep all the images in a global list.
